# Почему может происходить ошибка загрузки сборки у модуля?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, prism

Я использую систему модулей `WPF` совместно с `Prism`.

Все шло хорошо, до тех пор, пока я не добавил один [нагет пакет](https://www.nuget.org/packages/VirtualizingWrapPanel/) `VirtualizingWrapPanel`.

В разметке все настроил, но как только собрал модули, и загрузчик модулей `Prism` попытался инициализировать `View`, тут же произошло падение:

> FileNotFoundException: Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку
>   "VirtualizingWrapPanel, PublicKeyToken=null" либо одну из их
>   зависимостей. Не удается найти указанный файл.

Но на самом деле рядом с модулем лежит данный файл.
[image: Папка с модулями / плагинами]
Подгружать эту библиотеку должен модуль `WOAF.Module.MoonWalk`.

XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WOAF.Module.MoonWalk.Views.FeedSerialsView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
             xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:WOAF.Module.MoonWalk.Converters"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:WpfToolkit.Controls;assembly=VirtualizingWrapPanel"
             Background="LightGray"
             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True">
    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
        <ItemsControl Padding="3" ItemsSource="{Binding Feed.Report.Serials, IsAsync=True}" AlternationCount="2">
            <ItemsControl.Resources>
                <converters:UriToImageBrushConverter x:Key="UriToImageBrushConverter" />
            </ItemsControl.Resources>
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <controls:VirtualizingWrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <!--[Data template removed]-->
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
</UserControl>
```

Можно как-то решить данную проблему?

```
public partial class App
{
    protected override Window CreateShell()
    {
        return Container.Resolve<MainWindow>();
    }

    protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    {
    }

    protected override IModuleCatalog CreateModuleCatalog()
    {
        return new DirectoryModuleCatalog
        {
            ModulePath = @".\\Plugins\\"
        };
    }
}
```

[image: Нагет пакеты и зависимости модуля]

Comment: Пробовали выключить/включить студию, удалить/добавить пакет, удалить и добавить ссылку на сборку руками?

Comment: Да, пробовал, это не помогает. Все остается так же, единственное что спасает ситуацию, это положить данную библиотеку рядом с исполняемым файлом. По другому никак, но так не должно быть, т.к. модуль загружается, и выгружается, и он вообще может быть не установлен на ПК юзера.

Comment: `единственное что спасает ситуацию, это положить данную библиотеку рядом с исполняемым файлом. По другому никак, но так не должно быть`. Если вы не переопределяете путь поиска сборок, то как раз так все и должно быть. У вас же ссылка в проекте жесткая. Соответственно поиск происходит при старте приложения и поиск начнется в директории исполняемого файла

Comment: @Vasek, вы немного путаете загрузку библиотеки из другой папки с модулями `Prism`, У меня проект вообще не ссылается ни на какие сборки, т.е. сам `exe`
.

Comment: ну так сборка должна рядом с модулем лежать. Как модуль без сборки то загрузится?

Comment: @tym32167, модуль загружается, но зависимости нет, т.е. даже модуль на который он ссылается подгружается, но вот эта библиотека, нет.

Comment: То есть `Prism` загружается либы из папки отличной от папки расположения exe?

Comment: Если бы не было зависимости, то не было бы и ошибки. Или я не понял о чем вы вообще

Comment: @Vasek PRISM может грузить по разному, хоть из произвольной папки сборки подгружать

Comment: @tym32167, у модуля да, зависимость есть, но у основного приложения, которое загружает этот модуль при его наличии нет. https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdpb2.png, а зависимая библиотека лежит прямо рядом с модулем, не приложением, и не загружается.

Comment: Если `Prism` не исправляет пути поиска(а похоже он это не [делает](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650778/prism-assembly-reference-failure-system-windows-interactivity)), то будет использован стандартный механизм поиска. Соответственно если ваш модуль и его зависимости будут в папке в которой стандартный механизм не ищет, то произойдет примерно следующие: Prism загрузит ваш модуль из какой то папки -> стандартный загрузчик сборок увидит зависимость на другую сборку и начнет её искать -> так зависимоя сборка находится вне стандартных путей поиска он ёё не находит и выдает исключение.